# WebView falsely shows my "no connection"-page

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I've made a WebView where it checks internet connection and if there is none it will display an error-page.

It worked just fine until it recently when it would just display the error-page even though me having cellular data on, this persists even on WiFi's.

```
package se.welovecode.tismatapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView myWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.welovecode.se/t-matapp");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

        }
    });
    }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return false;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");` instead of using `myWebView();`

Comment: Should that fix it or just a tip?

Comment: It should fix it. If it doesn't we will figure out. Lets start from something atleast?

Comment: It seems to work on my friends phone (SGS5) but not on my phone (OPO), any idea?

Comment: Can you add the code where you are checking if internt is available?

Comment: I use the "onRecievedError" but the problem has been fixed. It was something on the server side so the guy who has responsability for that fixed it. Going to ask what he did so I can post it